# Custom index.html javadoc page?

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I am running javadoc with ant task:

```
<target name="javadoc"  description="create javadoc">
    <delete dir="javadoc" />
    <mkdir dir="javadoc" />
    <javadoc destdir="javadoc">
        <fileset dir="src/main/java" includes="sk/**" />
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

I'd like to change default index.html page for providing short user guide. I can alter index.html copy it to other place and rewrite it after ant task for javadoc is complete, but that seems little stupid. Is there more common way to achieve so? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for the -overview option of javadoc. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#overviewcomment for details.

Answer (score 3):

In Ant, you need to use the `overview` attribute like so:

```
<javadoc destdir="javadoc" overview="src/overview.html">...</javadoc>
```